# Why do I get a Laravel Composer Parsing Error?

Tags: php, json, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I'm getting the following error in my composer.json file in Laravel...

> Error: Parse error on line 10:
>    ...l": "~2016.04",    }, "require-dev"
>
> ----------------------^
>
> Expecting 'STRING'

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "aimeos/aimeos-laravel": "~2016.04",
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan vendor:publish --tag=public --force",
            "php artisan vendor:publish",
            "php artisan migrate",
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the last comma from the end of each array.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "aimeos/aimeos-laravel": "~2016.04"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan vendor:publish --tag=public --force",
            "php artisan vendor:publish",
            "php artisan migrate",
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use "," at the end of last object, It tells composer there is another string after this and composer doesn't found any other string. So you will face this type of error...

Remove that comma and happy coding..

Answer (score 1):

You can't have trailing commas in a JSON object or array, you need to remove them from the following lines

```
"aimeos/aimeos-laravel": "~2016.04",

"symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove **,** on last line and better practice use **CMD commands** its easy for you . and when you use cmd its always download latest version and no errors in **composer.json**

```
composer require aimeos/aimeos-laravel
```